# Integrating PHPBB into CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, integration, phpbb

I have a full CMS and I want to integrate it with phpbb.
Basically I want when user registers -> registers with phpbb and same with login.
Is there any good tutorial or something that can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279655/how-can-i-integrate-users-logins-from-my-site-into-phpbb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630027/use-phpbb2-login-credentials-in-my-sit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227261/use-phpbb-credentials-for-a-blog

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the CMS you are using, you will need what phpBB team calls Bridges. You have several existing, and the most powerful is clearly the Drupal Bridge

http://www.forum-software.org/phpbb3/review